# Allow Anonymous Access to Reports

Tags: java, jasperserver

I am trying to Direct url access to reports with no auth.
After doing all kind of setting available online i am getting the

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Please help me out,Any kind of help would be very appreciable.

I am working on the jasperserver 6.0.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented that by using the direct URL access for reports via Jasperserver. 
You can implement that by using an Iframe.:-)